# ¿Para que sirve y como se utiliza el "allowbackup" en Android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Si, el nombre de la propiedad suele ser obvio, pero no esta funcionando como yo lo esperaba.

```
<manifest ... >
...
<application android:allowBackup="true" ... >
    ...
</application>
```

Hice una aplicación tonta en Android con una base de datos SQLite para probar esta funcionalidad. Supuestamente con esta propiedad activada (y que viene activada por default en API 23+) puedo recuperar la base de datos `SQLite` una vez vuelto a instalar en el Teléfono, ya que la base de datos es alojada en el Google Drive de la cuenta de usuario de google actual puesta.

Instale y desinstale para probar, pero los resultados no fueron los esperados. Si desinstalo la aplicación y la vuelvo a instalar, los datos se pierden. Si esa misma aplicación solo lo reinstalo los datos se mantienen.

> Como entonces puedo hacer funcionar esta propiedad? (al desinstalarlo
>   y volverlo a instalar pueda recuperar la base de datos interna de la
>   aplicación?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De la documentación oficial:

> **[android:allowBackup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#allowbackup)**
>
> Ya sea para permitir que la aplicación participe en la infraestructura
>   de copia de seguridad y restauración. Si este atributo se establece en
>   falso, nunca se realizará una copia de seguridad o restauración de la
>   aplicación, incluso con una copia de seguridad del sistema completo
>   que de lo contrario haría que todos los datos de la aplicación se
>   guardaran a través de adb. El valor predeterminado de este atributo es
>   verdadero.

En este caso si defines en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:allowBackup="true"
```

Defines que al realizar una copia de seguridad, tu aplicación se incluirá en esta y al restaurar se agregara a tu dispositivo nuevamente.

---

> Como entonces puedo hacer funcionar esta propiedad? (al desinstalarlo
>   y volverlo a instalar pueda recuperar la base de datos interna de la
>   aplicacion?)

No funciona al desinstalar la aplicación y volver a instalarla, funciona al realizar una copia de seguridad ("Backup") de tu dispositivo, si restauras esta copia nuevamente a tu dispositivo se incluirá la aplicación.

Answer (score 2):

Hola el atributo `android:allowBackup="true"`sirve para que cuando una persona realize una copia de seguridad o un backup de su dispositivo, tu aplicacion pueda ser parte, si pones `false` y se realiza una restauracion del telefono tu app estara como recien descargado de tienda.

Mas info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element